# Unity shows compile errors for errors that do not actually exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Today I downloaded a Unity project and tried to build it, which I have not done before (I am a complete beginner when it comes to anything non-web based). When I opened the project, it told me to enter Safe Mode to resolve compile errors, which I did and found that these supposed errors did not exist! For every single class and void definition in two .cs files, Unity is telling me that it is defined more than once, but after checking the files, everything is only defined one time. These errors are preventing me from building. How can I fix this? I have already made sure all the dependencies are installed, and I have not made any modifications to the code after downloading it.

Edit: Here are the errors displayed in the console:

```
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(12,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'RhythmHeavenMania.Editor' already contains a definition for 'GridGameSelector'
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelectorGame.cs(6,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'RhythmHeavenMania.Editor' already contains a definition for 'GridGameSelectorGame'
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelectorGame.cs(12,22): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelectorGame' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelectorGame.cs(17,21): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelectorGame' already defines a member called 'OnClick' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(27,22): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(100,21): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'SelectGame' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(117,22): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'AddEvents' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(148,22): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'DestroyEvents' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(44,21): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'Drag' with the same parameter types
Assets\Scripts\LevelEditor\GridGameSelector.cs(62,21): error CS0111: Type 'GridGameSelector' already defines a member called 'Drop' with the same parameter types
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the console errors?

Comment: @JOYSONST, the image has been added.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JOYSONST: Images of code or errors are not acceptable here, so please do not ask for them.

Comment: I think you are having two scripts with the same class name and everything. Just search for the file and delete the one that your'nt using anymore.

Comment: I suggest you open the file in Visual Studio/Rider/another serious IDE via double click from within Unity and then simply do a search for the according type .. Rider e.g. would already tell you in which other file it is defined already .. not sure about VS